# snprintf() does not work for modifying a string in-place

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation

```
char symbols[16] = "";
int index = 0;
while (1)
{
     if (index % 2)
         snprintf(symbols, sizeof symbols, "a%s", symbols);
     else
         snprintf(symbols, sizeof symbols, "b%s", symbols);

     index++;

     printf("%s\n", symbols);
}
```

How output looks: a => bb => aaa => bbbb

I want the output looks: a => ba => aba => baba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour. From the C99 standard section *7.19.6.5 The snprintf function*:

> The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output is written into
>   an array (specified by argument s) rather than to a stream. If n is zero, nothing is written,
>   and s may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the n-1st are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end
>   of the characters actually written into the array. **If copying takes place between objects
>   that overlap, the behavior is undefined.**

You will need to make a copy of `symbols` for use as an argument in the `snprintf()` calls:

```
char symbols[16] = "";
char symbols_copy[16];
int index = 0;
while (index++ < 15)
{
     memcpy(symbols_copy, symbols, sizeof(symbols));

     if (index % 2)
         snprintf(symbols, sizeof symbols, "a%s", symbols_copy);
     else
         snprintf(symbols, sizeof symbols, "b%s", symbols_copy);

     printf("%s\n", symbols);
}
```

See demo http://ideone.com/GvnW7D .

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without `snprintf` too, of course:

```
char symbols[16] = "";
for(int i=0; i<15; ++i) {
    memmove(&symbols[1], symbols, i);

    if (i % 2) {
        symbols[0] = 'a';
    } else {
        symbols[0] = 'b';
    }
    printf("%s\n", symbols);
}
```